# Boyce Codd Normal Form?

Tags: database, database-design, normalization, bcnf

I want to see if these examples are in BCNF to know if I'm doing these correctly. 
The relation:

```
Employee (EID, Ename, PID, ProjectName, MID, ManagerName)
```

Functional Dependencies:

```
EID==>(Ename, PID)
PID==>(ProjectName, EID, MID)
MID==>(ManagerName, PID)
```

BCNF Relations:

```
Employees(EID,Ename, PID)
Project(PID, ProjectName)
Managers(MID, ManagerName, PID)
```

2nd Example

Relation:

```
Pet (PID, Pname, Type, Breed, DOB, OwnerID, OwnerName, OwnerPhone,
     OwnerEmail, ServiceType, Date, Charge)
```

Functional Dependencies:

```
PID==>(Pname, Type, Breed, DOB, OwnerID)
OwnerID==>(OwnerName, OwnerPhone, OwnerEmail, PID)
ServiceType==>(Charge)
```

BCNF Relations:

```
Pet(PID,Pname,Type,Breed,DOB)
Owner(OwnerID,  OwnerName, OwnerPhone, OwnerEmail, PID)
Service(ServiceType, PID, Date, Charge)
```

Am i on the right track with these?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both examples are in BCNF.

```
Employees(EID, Ename, PID)
Project(PID, ProjectName)
Managers(MID, ManagerName, PID)
```

There is no functional dependency, so BCNF is reached. Be aware though that in this example a project can be lead by many managers, but a manager can only lead one project.

```
Pet(PID ,Pname, Type, Breed, DOB)
Owner(OwnerID, OwnerName, OwnerPhone, OwnerEmail, PID)
Service(ServiceType, PID, Date, Charge)
```

Again this is BCNF, as the attributes have no dependencies which would lead to redundancy. And again be aware: The same pet can be owned by many owners, but an owner can only have one pet. Here is an example where each pet is owned by one owner only and one owner can have many pets:

```
Pet(PID, Pname, Type, Breed, DOB, OwnerID)
Owner(OwnerID,  OwnerName, OwnerPhone, OwnerEmail)
Service(ServiceType, PID, Date, Charge)
```